Server Side Handling HTTP Request Post Data in Python
For client side, I use Swift to make Post HTTP request as follows:
static func postNonceToServer(paymentMethodNonce: BTPayPalAccountNonce, deviceData: String) {

        let paymentURL = URL(string: "http://server.example.com/shop/transac")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: paymentURL)
        request.httpBody = "payment_method_nonce=(paymentMethodNonce)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            
            if let data = data {
                print("success data from postNonceToServer", data)
            } else if let error = error {
                print("error from postNonceToServer", error)
            } else {
                print("what happen from postNonceToServer")
            }
        }.resume()
    } 

On the server side, I would like to use Python and Django for http POST requests.
    def post(self, request):

        result = gateway.transaction.sale({
            "amount": "10.00",
            "payment_method_nonce": nonce_from_the_client,
            "options": {
                "submit_for_settlement": True
                }
            })

        if result.is_success:
            return Response(true, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(false, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

but the question is, on the server side, how do I access the POST request body data "payment_method_nonce" and "device_data" in "def post"?
Note that I could not use Json to send the POST request since BTPayPalAccountNonce is not json encryptable.
Great appreciate your help!

What is BTPayPalAccountNonce? If it's not JSON encodable, Python probably can't understand it without serialization or marshaling. Regardless, the request body is accessible as request.body. Inspect request.body with a debugger and start from there.
